# Continuity/differentiability at a point

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Consider the function
>   $$f(x)={\begin{cases}\arctan({ \frac{\tan{x}}{2} })&{\mbox{ for }}x <\frac{\pi}{2} \\\arctan({ \frac{\tan{x}}{2} })+\pi&{\mbox{ for }}x>\frac{\pi}{2} \\\end{cases}}$$
>   Show that $f$ can be defined at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, in such a way that the function is continuous at that point. Check if $f$ becomes differentiable in this way at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Honestly, I'm completely clueless. Any tips on how to solve this one?

Comment: Check left and right limits of the function at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. First you have to find the limits
$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-}\arctan( \tan(x)/2)=L_-\quad \mbox{and}\quad\lim_{x\to \pi/2^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \pi/2^+}\arctan( \tan(x)/2)+\pi=L_+.$$
Then $f$ can be extended by continuity at $\pi/2$ iff $L_+=L_-$.

If this happens, let $f(\pi/2):=L_+=L_-$. 
Then differentiability follows iff the following limit exists and it is finite
$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{f(x)-f(\pi/2)}{x-\pi/2}.$$
For the above limit you may use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: I would like to ask, when solving the last limit: Do I check both one sided limits and replace with the given $f(x)$, depending on the side? Because doing so I get that both one-sided limits are equal and that the function is differentiable at the point.

Comment: Yes both side withthe related formulas. You are correct the limits are the  both equal to 2